# Axios cannot get WP Json from WordPress Headless CMS

Tags: wordpress, axios, shared-hosting, wordpress-rest-api

I have a JSON data which I want to get from my wordpress headless CMS [site here](https://jameslaiproductions.ml/wp-json/wp/v2/posts).

```
const wpUrl = "https://jameslaiproductions.ml/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
```

However, I received a network error when getting data from this url.


On the other hand, I am successful in getting data from  any of the two url below:

```
const wpUrl = "https://test.frontity.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
const wpUrl = "https://oncoinfo.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
```

I suspect that the issue is with my WordPress or shared server hosting settings. But I can't seem to identify the problem & solution to this problem. Please refer to the sandbox link below to view the replicated problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sanderson-zpm8n?file=/src/component/Test01.js

Answer (score 0):

My webhost service provider (Infinity Free) has responded that this cannot work due to its security system. [More info here](https://support.infinityfree.net/websites/javascript-error-using-api-or-mobile-android-app/).



Now moving on to my next question;

1. Is there any way to work around this? If yes, how?
2. Which free web hosting service provider is recommended for me to be able to retrieve data from WP-Json?